# MongoDB query multiple values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've a User model similar to this:

```
{
  email: String,
  name: String,
  role: String,
  location: {
    country: String,
    city: String
  },
  contacts: {
    email: String,
    phone: String
  }
}
```

My idea is to show in the Homepage the following information:

- each User with details.
- Each Country with number of users in that Country.
- Each City in that Country with number of users in that City.

So, in the header I wish to have a Country list:

- UK (219)
- Germany (128)
- France (87)
- Italy (84)
- etc...

For each Country a list of cities:

- London (119)
- Liverpool (76)
- Manchester (3)
- etc...

And in the body the list of Users...

My query at the moment works fine for everything but cities.

The query is:

```
User.aggregate([
        { 
            $group: { 
                _id: { country: '$location.country' },
                users: { $push: '$$ROOT' },
                cities: { $addToSet: '$location.city' },
                count: { $sum: 1 }
            }
        }
    ], function(err, results) {

        console.log(results);

    });
};
```

It will be nice to have the `$sum` within the `$addToSet`, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

How can I improve this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a mongo query that does what you are asking for:

```
User.aggregate([
  { $group: { _id: { city: "$location.city", country: "$location.country" }, users: { $push: "$$ROOT" }, count: { $sum: 1 } } },
  { $group: { _id: "$_id.country", count: { $sum: "$count" }, cities: { $push: { city: "$_id.city", count: "$count", users: "$users" } } } }
], function(err, results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it has just a problem: I have an array of cities like ['London', 'London', 'London', etc...] and the count is right.
I was using addToset to avoid the City repeat... How can I have only a single City for each City and the number of User in that city?

Comment: I am not seeing that behavior. Are you sure you implemented it correctly? It should be grouping by city and country in the first `$group`, so there would only be a single 'London' when it gets to the second `$group`.

Comment: oh, well, it works fine now! It was an error on my logs! Cheers

Comment: one more question: how can I keep few values from the first `$group` like the total count of users in order to have also a record: `total users: n`. Ty

Comment: Probably the best solution for that is to add up the country totals in the code from `results`. Another possibility would be to just do a separate `Users.count({},function(err, count) {});` But if you feel you really must have the total user count calculated by mongodb in the same command, please ask a new question because I don't want to pollute the answer for the original question and the [margin of this comment is too small to contain the answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem).

Comment: Well, I created one more detailed question... I'm going ahead slowly with tons of questions lol: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27799780/mongodb-query-should-return-many-information