# MongoDB query should return many information

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm still a beginner with MongoDB and I'm getting crazy to create a complex (for me) query with it.

So, my model is:

```
{
  email: String,
  name: String,
  orientation: String,
  location: {
    country: String,
    city: String
  },
  contacts: {
    phone: String,
    email: String,
    website: String
  }
}
```

Now I created a query like this:

```
User.aggregate([
    { 
      $group: { 
        _id: { city: '$location.city', country: '$location.country', orientation: '$orientation' },
        count: { $sum: 1 }
      }
    },
    {
      $group: { 
        _id: '$_id.country',
        count: { $sum: '$count' },
        cities: { 
          $push: { 
            city: '$_id.city', 
            count: '$count'
          }
        },
        orientations: {
            $push: {
                orientation: '$_id.orientation',
                count: '$count'
            }
        }
      }
    }
  ], function(err, results) {
    if (err) return next();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
  });
```

Unfortunately I receive good data but just in part.

What I wish to have is a record with:

- **total users** (I don't have it)
- **total users in each Country** (I have it)
- **total users in each City** (I have it)
- **total users for each orientation** (I don't have it, I have total users for each orientation for each city)
- **total users for each orientation in each city** (I have it)

Currently it return:

```
[{
    "_id": "France",
    "count": 1,
    "cities": [{
        "city": "Maël-Carhaix",
        "count": 1
    }],
    "orientations": [{
        "orientation": "a",
        "count": 1
    }]
}, {
    "_id": "United Kingdom",
    "count": 4,
    "cities": [{
        "city": "Bagshot",
        "count": 1
    }, {
        "city": "London",
        "count": 3
    }],
    "orientations": [{
        "orientation": "a",
        "count": 1
    }, {
        "orientation": "a",
        "count": 3
    }]
}]
```

This is what I would like to have:

```
"totalUsers": 5,
"countries: [{
    "_id": "France",
    "count": 1,
    "cities": [{
        "city": "Maël-Carhaix",
        "count": 1
    }],
    "orientations": [{
        "orientation": "a",
        "count": 1
    }]
}, {
    "_id": "United Kingdom",
    "count": 4,
    "cities": [{
        "city": "Bagshot",
        "count": 1
    }, {
        "city": "London",
        "count": 3
    }],
    "orientations": [{
        "orientation": "a",
        "count": 4
    }, 
    {
        "orientation": "b" // if exist...
        "count: // n...
    }]
}]
```

I think to have changed this query hundreds of times but I'm at the 60% of the opera.

Comment: Advice. Slightly wrong approach in your question, so the the good way to do it. 1. List sample documents (just a few) 2. Show what result you want 3. (Because we like effort) show what you have tried. There is no simpler way to explain what you want to get than providing examples and effort.

Comment: I think there is already everything you need to see and understand what I did and what I need.

Comment: If that's true then why did I ask? All you have really shown is "what you tried". Schema is irrelevant, show data. This in MongoDB and mongoose or spring data or whatever is largely irrelevant to the problem to be solved. Dot points also are not a real explaination of a result. Add data for original and the desired result. Then it is clear.

Comment: Well, I added what it return at the moment. As you can see there is no value for a total users (it should be 5 following that log), and there is no total users for each orientation (all "a" at the moment) that should be 5, 1 in France and 4 in UK.

Comment: I just improved the formatting of the result.

Comment: I also added a result I would like to have... Thanks

Comment: Do you need total distinct users? Is the e-mail field your unique identifier?

Comment: I wish to have all users in array, but not very important to be honest. Much more important is the total number of orientation for each country / country - city.

Comment: @datasci id or email, I didn't wrote the entire model.

Answer (score 0):

For total users you could do:

```
db.collection.distinct("email").length
```

For total users for each orientation, you may be able to do this (assuming count in your model is that of unique users):

```
db.collection.group({
   key: {"orientations.orientation": 1 },
   reduce: function(cur, result) { result.count += cur.count },
   initial: { count: 0 }
})
```

In the future, as Niel has already mentioned, it's best to provide the full model (even if you input fake data) so that we can help you and write answers that actually make sense.

Comment: These are all separate calls to the DB. I was wondering if it is possible to get all these information with a single DB query to avoid multiple requests...
The Model is full, there isn't the ID and created / updated date... Not important for what I need.
On the question there are all the information: The model, my User.aggregate attempt, the output and what I would like to have...